# Load libraries in dist application, which are not known at build time

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.3

We want to deploy additional third party libraries (which name we dont know at build time) into a dist application, without requiring to rebuild it. Play should load them automatically on start.

We tried to copy them to the lib folder, that doesnt work. We saw that there is a generated classpath in the start script which is very restrictive (no wildcards). Can we somehow tell play to load all libraries in the lib folder? Or do we have to post modify the generated start script and add our libraries to the classpath string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this to your build.sbt file:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.Keys._

scriptClasspath := Seq("*")
```

this will make the generated script use wildcards instead of specifying each of the jars. Note that this can cause you problems if the order of the jars is important...

There is an [issue](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/72) related to too long command names in Windows that despite not directly related to your problem, suggest some workarounds that may apply to your problem.